# Shopware6 rest api for multi image upload

Tags: shopware

I am using Shopware 6, I am trying to upload multiple images how to upload multiple images upload by rest Api?

Answer (score 0):

I believe even if you upload multiple images via the backend, it makes separate requests. So I am not sure if there is such a thing like a multi upload.

Additionaly there is usually a size limit due to your web server and PHP settings, so it makes not much sense to combine multiple images into one request.

What keeps you from doing multiple uploads in a loop?